# How can I save a plot from R to scale?

Tags: r, image, plot, save

I have been experimenting with saving a plot that would display to scale because the nature of the plots I created tend to look really bad when squished like this:

[image]

So when I manually drag and click the plot in R itself, I can scale it to look good. Obviously, for longer words that I want to insert, the picture gets even more crammed. Is there a way for the plot itself to save as a jpeg not so squished but widened out a bit so it can look more decipherable? This is the part of the code in question:

```
jpeg("real.jpg")
plot(reg$fitted,reg$resid,type="n",main="Residual Plot of Your Name!", xlab = " ", ylab = " ", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
points(reg$fitted,reg$resid,pch=16)
dev.off()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "to scale" here? Do you mean like a fixed aspect ratio so a change in x is the same unit change in y? You can set `asp=1` in the `plot()` command for that. If you want to change the size of the resulting image you can set `width=` and `height=` values in your `jpeg()` call. It expects values in pixels by default.

Comment: Yes I was a bit unsure of how I can toggle the size relative to the picture. I think I'll give that a try thank you!

Comment: If you were to use RStudio, the Plots pane where you view the plots has an Export button. That will pop up the graphic, let you drag the borders to "scale" it how you want, and then save or copy it to the clipboard as such. I would recommend doing it by code instead because that is more reproducible way, but sometimes the quick and dirty is helpful.